# Issue with Nuxt 3/Vue 3 and class binding

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a weird situation, and I am not sure if it's related to Vue's composition API.

I have a listener that triggers a class for responsiveness. The listener works fine; the event gets captured, and the value that was supposed to trigger the class is not updating.

I added the two console.logs to follow the value as it happens, and there it shows that the `showFilter` values was updated (the first is false, and the second is true. But inside the template, rendering the {{ showFilter}}, it is always false, never gets updated.

First time using these wrappers without the normal exports default. What am I missing?

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { $listen, $ref, $bus } = useNuxtApp()

const { data, error } = await useAsyncQuery(query)
let showFilter = false

const closeFilter = ()=> {
  $ref.showFilter = false
  $bus.$emit('showMobileFilter', false)
}

const test = computed(() => showFilter)

onMounted(() => {
  $bus.$on("showMobileFilter", e => {
    console.log(showFilter, 1)
    showFilter = true
    console.log(showFilter, 2)
  })
})

</script>

<template>
  {{ showFilter }}
  <div :class="showFilter ? 'max-lg:absolute z-10' : 'max-lg:hidden'"
    class="lg:w-[250px] bg-brand-black border-r border-gray text-pure-white px-5 lg:px-7 py-5 lg:py-10 w-full lg:block">
    <div class="flex lg:hidden items-center justify-between">
      <span class="text-pure-white font-semibold pb-5">Filter</span>
      <button @click="closeFilter"><svg width="24" height="23" viewBox="0 0 24 23" fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M16.2427 7.36992L7.75739 15.2841M16.2427 15.284L7.75739 7.36987" stroke="white" stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: showFilter is not reactive. Use Vue composition api for ant reactive values

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried that, but I couldn't make it work. Do you mind elaborating on an answer?

Comment: `const showFilter = ref(false)`. The use of $ref.showFilter is confusing, I don't use Nuxt much but I don't think you'd need that, not to mention it doesn't interfere with showFilter  value

Comment: @EstusFlask beautiful, it worked. If you want to compose an answer, I will accept it.